# Prevent state change updates

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Entity Framework in a Blazor server side project, and I have a page where a user can edit data.  I have a Cancel button on the edit page that updates the Entity Framework context object to cancel pending changes in it, and then redirects to another page.  When the user hits Cancel, you can see values change back to their original values on the page before the redirect happens.  So there is unnecessary client updating happening here which is causing extra network traffic.  Is there a way to tell Blazor to not go through the state change process so I can prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried setting a boolean variable to false in your Cancel button event, then implement the ShouldRender override and return that boolean - this should prevent a re-render of the component. You will need to make sure that boolean is initialised to true or your component will never render

Comment: Provide (an outline of) the code.

Comment: Thanks Mister Magoo, that works though it's a few more steps than I hoped for.  If you change your comment into the form of answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

It would be nice if you could show some code and make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but since you didn't, I will give you a theoretical answer.

What you could do is have a "dummy" class for holding the values on the user client and have a class that will be manipulated by the server side, so you can manipulate when the data in the client side should change or not.

When the user edit the data, it will edit the dummy class and then map the values to the correct class, but when the user clicks on cancel, that won't be there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that seems like overkill for a minor issue like this.  I was hoping for a one line command, if there is such a thing.